# What's the difference between referencing an object by specifying an exact class and System.Object?

Tags: c#, types, reference, covariance

If we had a class, say `MyClass`, when instantiating an object of that class, what is the difference between these two:

```
Object obj=new MyClass();
MyClass obj2=new MyClass();
```

I know that in .NET, all classes derive from `System.Object`, so that in this case, *obj* and *obj2* variables just contain references to the objects.

**However, is there any difference?**

**And if so, what is it, when using these two ways of instantiating objects?**

Comment: Try calling a method of MyClass on the `obj` variable and you'll quickly see the difference.

Comment: It means the static type (at compile time) of the variable is `Object` instead of `MyClass`, and the dynamic type (at runtime) is `MyClass`, so you will only be able to call the methods declared on the `Object` class (unless you *cast*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your class had a property called `Name`, if you used this,

```
Object obj = new MyClass();
```

and tried to use:

```
obj.Name = "George";
```

This would be a compiler error, because the Object class does not have a `Name` property.  This, however, would be fine:

```
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();
obj2.Name = "George";
```

because the `obj2` is a `MyClass`.  In short, in order to access a variable's class members (properties, methods, variables), that variable has to be of a type that has those members, or it needs to be cast to the necessary class:

```
((MyClass)obj).Name = "George";
```

However, constantly casting variables in order to get at their members is not good, as it requires extra CPU cycles and can lead to InvalidCastExceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Well ita a bit of a no brainer, of course you can instansiate your class as an object, but why? you would have to cast it as your class if you want to use anything from it.

Example using `DateTime`

```
object obj = new DateTime();
int test = ((DateTime)obj).Second;   // Have to cast here, as object does not contain Second

DateTime obj2 = new DateTime();
int test2 = obj2.Second; // It is a DateTime so all good

var obj3 = new DateTime(); // Type is infered by right hand side assignment
int test3 = obj3.Second; // It is a DateTime so all good
```

So unless there in nothing in your class creating as object is fine, but then why use a class just use object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MYclass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object obj = new MYclass();
        MYclass mc = new MYclass();

        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
        MYclass mc2 = obj as MYclass;
        Console.WriteLine(mc2.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(mc.Id);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In the above snippet the output will be

```
ConsoleApplication1.MYclass
0
0
```

This tells you that at run time the type of obj is Myclass. However, at compile time it is still an Object and you need explicit casts to access theproperties of Myclass in obj.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `MyClass` inherits directly from `Object`, writing `Object obj = new MyClass()` creates a `MyClass` object but the reference to it is of type `Object`. It is therefore unaware of any publicly available methods, properties or state variables that exist in the class `MyClass`, so if you try and call:

`obj.MyClassMethod()`

the call will fail. The only methods available to `obj` will be those exposed by the `Object` class unless some form of casting is used.

Answer (score 0):

First: terminology. You are only instantiating the instance of MyClass in one way: by invoking its constructor. What you are doing is referring to the instance in two ways. This is because of polymorphism, the property where a class instance can be referred to by any type which it implements. There is no great distinction between the different ways of referring to the instances as you wrote it, but there can be when you want to perform some operation using some base type. The CLR performs automatic conversion from a subtype (MyClass) and its base type (Object).